# Save variable to session in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, session

This is the code inside of my Handler.ashx at the end of this loop I want to save the variable whereclause to the session so it will know what the previous where clause was.

I am open to any way of doing it, but I believe saving to the session would help me complete this.

I tried: `Session["whereclause"] = whereclause` but it gave me an error

```vb
'4.3 Filtering implementation
If Not (FilterTerm = "" Or FilterCol = "") Then
    If Not (FilterCol = "[Study Time]") And InStr(whereclause, "WHERE", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        whereclause = whereclause & " WHERE " & FilterCol & " = '" & FilterTerm & "'"
    ElseIf InStr(whereclause, "WHERE", vbTextCompare) = 0 And FilterCol = "[Study Time]" Then
        whereclause = whereclause & " WHERE " & FilterCol & " = '12/30/1899 " & FilterTerm & "'"
    ElseIf (FilterCol = "[Study Time]") Then
        whereclause = whereclause & " AND " & FilterCol & " = '12/30/1899 " & FilterTerm & "'"
    Else
        whereclause = whereclause & " AND " & FilterCol & " = '" & FilterTerm & "'"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Do you have `IReadOnlySessionState` or do you have `IRequiresSessionState`? You need the latter to be able to *write* to session state. Otherwise, you are going to have to tell us what the error is for us to have a chance of helping with this.

Comment: Imports System.Web.SessionState

Comment: In the overall declaration of the handler, there is something like `Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler`. You need that to be `Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState`.

Comment: Public Class Handler
    Implements IHttpHandler
    Implements IRequiresSessionState
    Public _context As HttpContext

Comment: okay I added that but how do I set it?

Comment: Please [edit] the question so that it includes the part with that code. Then we can see it in context to be sure that it is in the correct place. Also, please add the error message so that we can tell what the problem really is: I had to guess about that part.